# Maven install is launching browser but not opening URL and throwing error, build is failing

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:217)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:144)
at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:634)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:159)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Results :

Failed tests:   configBeforeMethod(package name): wrong number of arguments

If I run only with testNG xml its working fine. When am trying to run with Maven am getting the above error, and browser is launching but not opening any URL. 
Please help me here.

This is my pom.xml -

```
<groupId>Automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>Maven.Test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Maven.Test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
  <build>  
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins> 
  </build>
</project>
```

`

Am running this through eclipse IDE (Maven Install), I don't use command line now.

Comment: This needs more details in terms of pom configuration and maven command used to run this. Surefire version or other testng pertaining configuration in pom would be good to look at.

Comment: I have added my pom.xml file please do help. Thanks